# How to properly save/retrieve data from options page for google chrom extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was just wondering why my options data doesn't seem to retrieve data from previous load. I'm following https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/options/

To my knowledge, I believe restore_options() should be attempting to grab the previous data saved to the storage API, but on refresh it just seems to reset to its original values insetad. I'm also trying to console.log things from the options menu but I'm not sure where or if it's even logging, I've chcekd the popup logger and the service_worker logger.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Pondr",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Time finds you.",
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icons/pondr_16.png",
    "48": "assets/icons/pondr_32.png",
    "32": "assets/icons/pondr_48.png",
    "128": "assets/icons/pondr_128.png"
  },

  "action": {
    "default_icon": "assets/icons/pondr_128.png",
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "options_page": "options/options.html",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "alarms", "storage", "notifications", "downloads"],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["options/options.html"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "extension_ids": []
    }
  ]
}
```

```
// Saves options to chrome.storage
function save_options() {
  var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
  var likesColor = document.getElementById("like").checked;
  chrome.storage.sync.set(
    {
      favoriteColor: color,
      likesColor: likesColor,
    },
    function () {
      // Update status to let user know options were saved.

      var status = document.getElementById("status");
      status.textContent = "Options saved.";
      setTimeout(function () {
        status.textContent = "";
      }, 750);
    }
  );
}

// Restores select box and checkbox state using the preferences
// stored in chrome.storage.
function restore_options() {
  // Use default value color = 'red' and likesColor = true.
  chrome.storage.sync.get(
    {
        favoriteColor: "red",
        likesColor: true,
    },
    function (items) {
      document.getElementById("color").value = items.favoriteColor;
      document.getElementById("like").checked = items.likesColor;
    }
  );
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", restore_options);
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", save_options);
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>My Test Extension Options</title>
</head>

<body>

    Favorite color:
    <select id="color">
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>
        <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
    </select>

    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="like">
        I like colors.
    </label>

    <div id="status"></div>
    <button id="save">Save</button>

    <script src="options.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script already runs after DOMContentLoaded.

Replace `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", restore_options)`
with  `restore_options()`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I accepted your answer as the solution. I'm fairly new to extensions and scripting, can you explain why that worked? And what DOMContentLoaded does?

Comment: And an additional question, how come when I try to console.log anything from this options menu, it doesn't show up anywhere?

Comment: You can read more about DOMContentLoaded in the documentation, just google it up. As for console.log, to open the correct devtools console right-click inside the options page, then click "inspect".